# Stacking traffic light shapes

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to do something very simple.  I need to create a basic traffic light shape with a rectangle and three circles within it.  I tried using SVG for the shapes but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the circles to overlap correctly over the rectangle.  It doesn't have to be interactive or anything.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you want help with an issue on this site, always at least show some of your own efforts. You cannot expect others to provide solutions from scratch for you... I am also doubtful this question deals with any of the topics suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I put one together using just HTML and CSS. View the Stack Snippet below or as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0mpj2cy/).

```css
.container{ background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30px;}
.red, .yellow, .green{border-radius: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 25px;}
.red{background: red;}
.yellow{background: yellow;}
.green{background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```